# Transform a map into a new map based on the pattern of keys in Scala

Tags: regex, scala

Given a map to find elements of a pattern of C{NUMBER} -> STRING; this is my code to do that.

```
val pattern = "C([0-9]+)".r
// find the elements C[0-9]+ format
val plots = smap filter { x =>
  x._1 match {
    case pattern(r) => true
    case  _ => false
  }
}
```

I need to extract the elements with the pattern, but to create a new map of Map[Int, String]. For example:

```
Map[String, String]("C1"->"a", "B", "C2"->"c") => Map[Int](1 -> "a", 2 -> "c")
```

How can it implemented in Scala?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here it is:

```
scala> val m = Map[String, String]("C1"->"a", "B" -> "M", "C2" -> "c")
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(C1 -> a, B -> M, C2 -> c)

scala> val P = "C([0-9]+)".r
P: scala.util.matching.Regex = C([0-9]+)

scala> val n = m collect { case (P(i), v) => (i.toInt, v) }
n: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(1 -> a, 2 -> c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an extractor that delivers an `Option[Int]`; namely

```
object NumStr {
  val re = "C(\\d+)".r
  def unapply(s: String): Option[Int] = {
    s match {
      case re(v) => Some(v.toInt)
      case _     => None
    }
  }
}
```

Thus we can iterate over

```
val a = Map[String, String]("C1" -> "a", "B" -> "M", "C2" -> "c")
```

to extract numerical values on the keys and create a new map, for instance like this,

```
for ( (NumStr(k),v) <- a ) yield k -> v
res: Map[Int,String] = Map(1 -> a, 2 -> c)
```

Note the for comprehension flattens (unsuccessful) extractions which resulted in `None`.

For a lengthy intro to extractors used together with regular expressions consider http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/extractors.html .